# How to find $\operatorname{Gal}(S/\mathbb{Q})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, cubics, splitting-field

Please help me to answer the following problem:

Let $f(x)=x^3-3x-5\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f(x)$ is irreducible and since $756$ is not the square of a rational number, [the answer is $S_3$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Galois_groups_of_irreducible_cubics).

Comment: We can also use that $3$ divides the order of the Galois group to show that it must be $S_3$.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos, I was thinking of $S_3$ but  how to prove that result?

Comment: @awllower But $3$ also divides the order of $A_3$.

Comment: I mean $3$ divides the order and it is not contained in $A_3$, so it must be $S_3$. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @siwar Did you not click the link from my answer? It provides a proof.

Comment: @awllower How do you know that it is not contained in $A_3$?

Comment: As in your answer, the discriminant of the polynomial is not the square of a rational number. I just pointed out that we don't need the transitivity of the group here.

Comment: Can i answer like this:  In general the Galois group of an irreducible separable cubic over the field $\mathbb{Q}$ is a transitive subgroup of $S_3$ and there are only two such subgroups: $S_3$ and $A_3$. it is A3 if the discriminant of the cubic is the square of an element of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $S_3$  otherwise. In our case we have $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ and its discriminant 756 is not a square of an element of $\mathbb{Q}$ thus up to isomorphism $Gal(L/Q)=S_3$

Comment: @siwar That is correct.

Comment: I have an other question is it possible to find an explicit expression of a root of $f(x)$ in term of radicals and use it to write a repeated radical extention $\mathbb{Q}\subset K$ such that $f(x)$ splits in $K$?

Comment: @siwar You have Cardano's formula for that.

Comment: how that? i don't know how to use it

Comment: i know it in general https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Cardano_formula but i don't know how to apply it in our case?

Comment: @siwar I could answer that, but then you would post it as if it had been done by you.

Comment: @siwar Let$$\Delta=\left(\frac{-6}2\right)^2+\left(\frac{(-2)^3}{27}\right)=\frac{235}{27}.$$Consider the extension field $\mathbb{Q}\left[\sqrt\Delta\right]$. Now, consider the field extension field $\mathbb{Q}\left[\Delta,\sqrt[3]{-\frac q2+\sqrt\Delta}\right]$. The roots are there.

Comment: how you determined $\Delta$? is there a general rule? and what is $q$?

Comment: @siwar Sorry: $q=-2$; it is the constant term of your polynomial. Did you see [Cardan's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano's_method)? I applied it with $p=-6$ and $q=-2$.

Comment: what are the roots of $f$ related to $\Delta$?

Comment: @siwar Take a look at Cardano's formula! It's all there.

Comment: Are they $t_k$? with $\zeta=e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}$?