# Explicit expression of a root

Tags: abstract-algebra

Please help me to answer the following problem:

Let $f(x)=x^3-6x-2\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and $L$ be a splitting field of $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

$f$ is irreducible  in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and its discriminant is $756$. Up to isomorphism  $\operatorname{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q})=S_3$

> Find an explicit expression of a root of $f(x)$ in term of radicals and use it to write a repeated radical extention $\mathbb{Q}⊂K$ such that $f(x)$ splits in $K$.

Comment: Use [Cardano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots)

Comment: For both @Jose and Dietrich: the question you linked to is **not** the same question as here...

Comment: @DietrichBurde It is **not** the same question.

Comment: I'm reopening this question as it was incorrectly closed.

Comment: @DonAntonio have you seen all the comments, Jose was giving as a help [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2623241/how-to-find-operatornamegall-mathbbq)? I cannot understand, why the OP then posts this very similar question again. But yes, you are right. I need to find an exact duplicate.

Comment: @DietrichBurde It is not the same question at all, even if it involves the same polynomial. Of course, you or anyone else can try to close it because it shows insufficient work or because it lacks details, but not because there was already the same question.

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes, understood.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you. Anyway, as you commented, using Cardano's formula for the cubic is a way to go here...perhaps the only more or less basic way to go.

Comment: The question before that was [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2623209/irreducibility-of-x3-6x-2-in-qx?rq=1) - I know, a different question...